# Getting the container from the given structure using selector

Tags: jquery

consider the following html structure:

```
<div>
     <div class="top">
        <div id="id1">123</div>
     <div>

     <div class="top">
        <div id="id2">123</div>
     <div>
</div>
```

Now I want to pick the container on the basis of class="top" and id="id2" in such a way that i get the container with class top. How can I do that? I would like to have some selector for that.

P.S: the id i am looking for is not necessarily to be an immediate parent of the class top.

Comment: you like to select only id2 div right

Comment: no i wanna select <div class="top"> who has inner div with id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('#id2').closest('.top')
```

It will start with the ID and travel up until it finds the class top.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.closest(...)`

```
$('#id2').closest('.top');
```

Or if your structure is always as you have it in the question, then maybe a simple,

```
$('#id2').parent();
```

will do.

Answer (score 0):

If by "container" you mean the markup, not the DOM element add this somewhere in javascript:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    return (s)
        ? this.before(s).remove()
        : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$('.top').outerHTML();
```